# node-sass not recompiling on page refresh during development

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I have recently started a new Node/express project and included the node-sass package for sass compilation. On the first page load, all assets are compiled, but subsequent refreshes fail to update assets if only imported files have been modified. Has anyone else had this issue, and is there a fix?

Comment: Yes, I've just found the same problem. No solution as yet. Did you manage to solve it in the end?

Comment: Not yet, but maybe the answer from Swervo will help. I have yet to try the solution though.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a solution as there appears to be a [problem in node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/157#issuecomment-58533058)

But adding:

```
force: true
```

does fix the problem.

Comment: I will have to give that a shot. Thanks for answering a relatively old question! I have been doing mostly rails Development since I asked this.